# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds looping through text file

Tags: java

I have loaded from text files many times before without thi issue, I have read and re-read my code and I (personally) cant see why I would get this issue, I am completely lost.

```
static public ArrayList<Media> importMedia(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        try {
            ArrayList<Media> mList = new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            int numberOfItems = Integer.valueOf(line);
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] split = line.split(",");
                if(split[0].contains("mp3"))
                {
                    Mp3 mp3 = new Mp3(split[1]/*title*/,split[0]/*filename*/,Integer.parseInt(split[4])/*releaseyear*/,split[2]/*artist*/,split[3]/*album*/,split[5]/*label*/,Double.parseDouble(split[6])/*runtime*/);
                    mList.add(mp3);
                }else if (split[0].contains("gif"))
                {
                    Gif gif = new Gif(split[1]/*title*/,split[0]/*filename*/,Integer.parseInt(split[6])/*releaseyear*/,Double.parseDouble(split[2])/*width*/,Double.parseDouble(split[3])/*height*/,split[4]/*equipName*/,split[5]/*equipModel*/);
                    mList.add(gif);
                }else if(split[0].contains("avi"))
                {
                    String castNames = "";
                    boolean first = true;
                    for(int i = 7; i < 15; i++)
                    {
                        if(!(split[i].isEmpty()))
                        {
                            if(first)
                            {
                                castNames += split[i];
                                first = false;
                            }else{
                                castNames += "," + split[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Avi avi = new Avi(split[1]/*title*/,split[0]/*filename*/,Integer.parseInt(split[3])/*releaseyear*/,split[2]/*studio*/,split[5]/*director*/,castNames/*castnames*/,Double.parseDouble(split[4])/*runtime*/,Integer.parseInt(split[6])/*cast*/);
                    mList.add(avi);
                }else{
                }
            }
            return mList;
        } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex.toString()); }
        return null;
    }
```

Now it will only get the first 3 files(Console shown in picture)
[image]

I am simply trying to loop through and I am not sure why it would be out of bounds, I cannot see anything wrong with the loop, or why its giving me some but not all.

Comment: Please modify your code to print the entire stack trace when an exception is caught. That will tell you what line is causing the exception and you can probably track down the problem from there. If not, update the question to provide more details.

Comment: Can you share stacktrace where exact it's throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception

Comment: I added the check and I believe I have found the problem, thanks for your help lads

Comment: can you provide a sample input? ( content of the text file )

Answer (score 0):

In this code you are using a String Array `split` from index 0 to index 14.

It would be good to do some defensive programming by checking length of String Array.

Please check the length of array before proceeding to use it in your programme.

like `split.length >14`

By using this habit you can always escape from '`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`'